# Is there an Android Equivalent to iMessage?

Tags: sms, instant-messaging

I don't get mobile reception at home and would love to be able to send and receive SMS either via the phone or by computer.  I currently use Skype to send SMS but can't receive that way.  I have tried a few apps but nothing seems to work unless you're in mobile range.  My daughter has an iPhone and she can send and receive SMS with ease.  I have a Samsung Galaxy S III.

I am in Australia so I need a service that is available here. Google Voice is not available here.

Comment: Ever consider [Viber](http://www.viber.com/)?

Comment: Viber won't work on computer. Wha about Google voice ?

Comment: Back to square one.  Google Voice not available in Australia, apparently.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are in Australia, I would suggest trying t0mm13b's suggestion of [Viber](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viber.voip). You will have to "Validate" your account with Viber in a location that you have mobile data connection, according to [this article](http://www.viberfaq.com/how-to-activate-viber-at-remote-location-in-australia/), first, but then you should be able to use the service just fine on wifi.

If available, [Google Voice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.googlevoice) is a good option. You will be able to send and receive SMS from it on both mobile network and wifi.

It is probably your best option as it doesn't require the other person to have a different application to be able to receive the messages. Most of them will require the person receiving the message to have the same application.

Google Voice doesn't require the other person to have a special application. It will send the messages as SMS. It will, however, require you to use the Google Voice application to send the messages.

Comment: One stickler to keep in mind about Google Voice: no MMS ([unless you are on Sprint and want to deal with weird workarounds](http://googlevoiceblog.blogspot.com/2011/10/first-steps-towards-mms-support.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [WhatsApp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp)? It's available on both iOS and Android. [Google Voice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.googlevoice) is the best option though if available in your country.

Comment: What's App plays a bit fast and loose with user data. http://www.cbc.ca/news/technology/story/2013/01/28/technology-whatsapp-privacy.html

Answer (score 0):

[Two ex-googlers](http://techcrunch.com/2012/06/19/ex-googlers-launch-mightytext-an-imessage-for-android-users/) created the app [MightyText](http://mightytext.net/). Give it a try:

- "Send & receive SMS and MMS from your computer or tablet, using your current Android phone number. Messages stay in sync with your phone's SMS inbox."
- "SMS directly from Gmail on your computer."
- "text from [your] phone as [you] normally would... in the U.S. or international."

Disclaimer: I haven't actually tested it in Australia ;) But I'd be happy to hear if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

There's not because iMessage is a private protocol developed by Apple. You can use [Telegram](https://telegram.org/).

If you have an Android phone and a Mac, there's an interesting app, [iMessage for Android](https://android-imessages.fortifiedlabs.com) which allows you to sync your Android texts with Apple Messages (iChat) app.

Answer (score 0):

The best application you can use for this purpose is [KiK Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kik.android&hl=en) . This will solve all your problem you dont need mobile reception for this. All the other apps actually map your account against your mobile number. But you can create account on kik without any mobile number.